# Blazor Razor return statement in HTML

Tags: razor, blazor

I recently inherited a Blazor project and come across many .razor files that are like:

```
<h1>Some header text></h1>
@if(someCondition) {
<div> lots of html and what not here taking up many lines</div>
} else {
<div> more html taking up many lines</div>
}
```

What I'm wondering is if there is a syntax that will allow me to eliminate the "else" statements that are hiding in the weeds, by having a return statement in my "if" condition.  Meaning:

```
<h1>Some header text></h1>
@if(someCondition) {
<div> lots of html and what not here taking up many lines</div>
return //JUST BAIL HERE INSTEAD OF HAVING TO START AN ELSE BLOCK LIKE I DO ELSEWHERE IN LIFE
}

<div> more html taking up many lines</div>
```

Comment: Render fragments are delegates. If you use `return;` the delegate will end and not render anything else. https://blazorrepl.com/repl/mPYJbVmu24lAEpVu29

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can use `return;` this ends the `RenderFragment` no other content is drawn.

[blazor repl](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/GvuJFVwb323qJtSg13)

Comment: It will result in a runtime exception in many situations.

Comment: Like any return mid method/delegate it becomes spaghetti code. Eric is right breaking your UI in Blazor should be similar to how your structure your code. Nobody encourages using returns mid method. Some tolerate early get out of here returns.

Comment: But there is difference - spaghetti code is hard to read/debug but it works. This will crash your application in scenarios that are fairly common.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, as [Brian's answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67577256/18938), but Razor encourages breaking your markup into components that can be composed easier. In this case, I would consider breaking out your `<div></div>` elements into their own components, making the resulting Razor simpler:

```
<h1>Some header text></h1>
@if(someCondition)
{
    <component1 />
}
else
{
    <component2 />
}
```

**Edited to add:**

Imagine trying to figure out why some giant chunk of markup is not rendering in some page, what with no conditionals surrounding it. Only to find that there's some unexpected `return` statement in the middle of the the component. I don't think I would react nicely if that were me.

Comment: No, you can. Like Brian says, you can totally use `return`. `RenderFragment`s are just delegates.

Comment: And so it is! Learn something new every day. I don't think I'd write my Razor views that way, though, and would still componentize them. But now I have something new to keep an eye out for.

Comment: @EricKing Totally agree akin to spaghetti code.

Comment: Or use `MarkupString` for static content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `return` and it will stop rendering at that point. However, it might result in runtime exception. Imagine you have a markup like this:

```
<div>
    @if(somecondition)
   {
      return;
   }
</div>
```

Here, the method will return without adding the closing `</div>` resulting in a runtime exception. You can check this by adding enclosing `<div>` around the if statement and removing the else condition in Brian Parker's repl.