# Blazor, return from/halt rendering if loading

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

We have similar code as below in all our Blazor pages, to simply halt the rendering until loading is done. It seems to work ok, but the site has not had that much testing yet.

I am a bit worried that this, meaning the *return;* in the middle of the page, will/could mess up blazors flow in one way or another, lead to memory leaks or whatever.

Every example I see uses if/else instead, but if the below example is valid it's much preferred to reduce nesting and complexity of the page.

So, is this method ok to use, or will it cause us problems down the line?

A simplified example:

```cs
@usings/injects here
    
@if (IsLoading)
{
    @:Loading content..
    return;
}
    
<p>This will not be rendered until page is initialized and Model populated</p> 
<p>@Foo.Bar</p>
    
@code {
    public bool IsLoading { get; set; } = true;
    public FooModel Foo { get; set;}
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            Foo = await GetFooFromRepo();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toaster.Add("Something went wrong when loading foo.", 
                 MatToastType.Danger, "Error");
        }
        finally
        {
            IsLoading = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of taste or style.

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with it, you are just returning form a method.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67575364/60761) it is likened to spaghetti code but that depends. The way you write this the `return` is very clear and hard to overlook. And the alternative `else { }` has its own reading costs.

Comment: Thanks - that "it's a matter of taste and style" is the perfect answer. I'll stick with this approach as I don't like to nest big chunks of markup within if/else.

Answer (score 5):

I would not use this approach,

The way I recommend to do this it would be with an [@if-else](https://www.webassemblyman.com/blazor/blazorifelseif.html) statement, like the follow:

```
@if (IsLoading)
{
    @:Loading content..
}
else 
{  
  <p>This will not be rendered until page is initialized and Model populated</p> 
  <p>@Foo.Bar</p>
}
```

Comment: Whats your reasoning?

Comment: Imagine trying to figure out why some giant chunk of markup is not rendering in some page, what with no conditionals surrounding it. Only to find that there's some unexpected return statement in the middle of the the component. I don't think I would react nicely if that were me. From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67575364/6442841

Comment: I see your point. In this case however, the code would always be on top of all other "html" markup, to keep it structured. Thanks for the input

Comment: Either way, would work and it is a matter of taste as @Henk said. But I would definitely use the @if-else approach. It's a matter of habit as well... With `if-else`, there are less chances to create spaghetti code in my opinion.

Comment: I see it more of a way to return quickly if the code allows, like most do in methods. I'm happy with the structure, I was mostly worried it would cause some problems in the blazor stack or js even.

Comment: I am not sure about that, but I couldn't find any article or doc about that. I guess that the templates are creating at runtime, so the `return;` is just finishing the template generation.